# C# Desktop recorder h.264 cross-"computer"

Tags: c#, .net, ffmpeg, directx, h.264

I was looking for a method with "least requirements" for a maximum compatibility.

I have seen that there are mainly 2 ways: through directx, through .NET ( only >Win7) but both requires Win7 Or DirectX 9 installed.

could `ffmpeg` be useful? I have tried following [this Wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20grab%20the%20desktop%20%28screen%29%20with%20FFmpeg), but it prompts me:

```
> ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="UScreenCapture":audio="Microphone" output.flv

[dshow @ 00000000003ea700] Could not find video device.
video=UScreenCapture: Input/output error
```

Any advice?

Comment: I know VLC can do this fairly easily, though not necessarily particularly efficiently. Still, you shouldn't generally ask questions on a 'how can i fix this code?' site pertaining to 'which software would Google suggest I use to solve my problem?'

Comment: Did you checked the reference implementation for H.264/AVC? http://iphome.hhi.de/suehring/tml/download/

Comment: @Magus I have already googled, and I have found difficulties in solutions I found ( and in my question I also posted "how can I fix this command line ffmpeg")

Comment: Why didn't you show your actual ffmpeg command and the complete ffmpeg console output?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard the error was that, just before it wrote down some list of dshow stream installed. I have discovered that stream "UScreenCapture" is not installed by default I have just found a program (http://www.umediaserver.net/bin/UScreenCapture.zip) that through an installer install it. So when I install my app I should have the user installed that program